# Vertical tab in SQL Server Management Studio - query and results side by side?

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2017

Does anyone know how to get the query on one side and the results on the other?

By default, the results are under the query script. I see how to use the vertical tab to get two scripts side by side, but the results are still stuck underneath. When I have just one script open, I don't see the vertical tab option.

On a laptop with small screen real estate, it would be really useful. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think side by side is available by default, but you can put them in a different tab and then move them side by side.

Tools > Options > Query Results > SQL Server > Results to Grid

Then check the *Display results in a separate tab*. You can also check *Switch to results tab after the query executes* which will probably help you, since it's what you'd want to see after the execution completes.

Comment: Is this the best we can do?  This does not put the editor on one side and the results on the other.  You can only see one tab at a time.

Guess I should turn my monitor to portrait lol